# What are efficient ways to compute the derivatives of iterated functions?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, recursion

The derivatives of iterated functions at a fixed point $z_0$ are useful in constructing a Taylors series of iterated analytic functions - in other words, the Taylors series of a dynamical system $f^t(z_0)$.

A simpler version of the problem casts light on possible approaches. Instead of iterated functions, consider composite functions and [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) The combinatorial structure [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_partition) serves as the index to the summations in Faà di Bruno's formula. So the first step of evaluation is to enumerate all integer partitions of a given order.

While combinatorial structure [integer partitions](http://oeis.org/A000041) are associated with the derivatives of composite functions, [the unlabeled version of the labeled combinatorial structure total partitions](http://oeis.org/A000669) are associated with iterated functions. See [Partition Diagrams](http://tetration.org/Combinatorics/PartitionDiagrams.htm) for more information on the different relevant combinatorial structures. The following Mathematica code does what I need, but the cost of simplicity is that it first enumerates the labeled total partitions to compute the unlabeled total partitions. So for $n=10$, $D^{10}f^t(z_0)$, there are 282,137,824 labeled total partitions, while there are only 2,312 unlabeled partitions.

### Combinatorial Examples

a(4)=5 unlabeled total partitions: (oooo),(oo(oo)),(o(ooo)),(o(o(oo))),((oo)(oo)).

b(4)=26 labeled total partitions: ((1,4),2,3), (1,(2,4),3), (1,2,(3,4)), (((1,4),2),3), ((1,(2,4)),3), ((1,2),(3,4)), (((1,4),3),2), ((1,(3,4)),2), ((1,3),(2,4)), ((1,4),(2,3)), (1,((2,4),3)), (1,(2,(3,4))), (1,2,3,4), ((1,2,4),3), ((1,2),3,4), ((1,3,4),2), ((1,3),2,4), (1,(2,3,4)), (1,(2,3),4), ((1,2,3),4), (((1,2),4),3), (((1,2),3),4), (((1,3),4),2), (((1,3),2),4), (1,((2,3),4)), ((1,(2,3)),4)

b(4) = 12 (o(o(oo))) + 3 ((oo)(oo)) + 6 ((oo(oo)) + 4 (o(ooo)) + (oooo) = 26

I would like to have an efficient way to reproduce the preceding results.

### Mathematica code

```
TotalPartitions[0] = {{}};
TotalPartitions[1] = {{1}};
TotalPartitions[2] = {{1, 2}};
Match[l_List, pattern_] := Extract[l, Position[l, pattern]];
TP1[l_List, next_Integer] := 
  Map[( l /. # -> {#, next}) &, Match[l, _Integer] ];
TP2[l_List, next_Integer] := 
  Map[( l /. # -> Append[#, next]) &, Match[l, _List] ];
TP3[l_List, next_Integer] := 
  Map[( l /. # -> {#, next}) &, Match[l, _List] ];
TotalPartitions[n_Integer] := 
  TotalPartitions[n] = 
   Flatten[ {Map[(TP1[#, n] ) &, TotalPartitions[n - 1]], 
     Map[(TP2[#, n] ) &, TotalPartitions[n - 1]], 
     Map[(TP3[#, n] ) &, TotalPartitions[n - 1]]}, 2];

u = TotalPartitions[4] /. _Integer -> 1
> {{{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}, {{1, {1, 1}}, 1}, 
>  {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
>  {1, {{1, 1}, 1}}, {1, {1, {1, 1}}}, 
>  {{1, 1}, 1, 1}, {1, {1, 1}, 1}, 
>  {1, 1, {1, 1}}, {{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}, 
>  {{1, {1, 1}}, 1}, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
>  {{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1, 1}, 
>  {1, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, {1, 1}, 1}, 
>  {1, 1, 1, 1}, {{1, 1, 1}, 1}, 
>  {{1, 1}, 1, 1}, {{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}, 
>  {{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}, {1, {{1, 1}, 1}}, 
>  {{1, {1, 1}}, 1}, {{1, 1, 1}, 1}, 
>  {{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}, {{{1, 1}, 1}, 1}}

SetAttributes[Z, Orderless];
Tally[Apply[List, Apply[Z, u, Infinity], Infinity]]
>  {{{1, {1, {1, 1}}}, 12}, {{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, 3}, {{1, 1, {1, 1}}, 6}, 
>   {{1, {1, 1, 1}}, 4}, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, 1}}
```

Note that the Tally function displays the number of occurrences of labeled total partitions for each unlabeled total partition, so that $12+3+6+4+1=26$ shows how the 5 unlabeled total partitions of order 4 map to the 26 labeled total partitions. I've tried pure analytic approaches, combinatorial approaches and a hybrid of the two in my Mathematica programs [Schroeder Summations and Iterate.](http://tetration.org/Resources/Files/Mathematica/SchroederSummations.nb) I believe this is a useful problem in dynamics and combinatorics and merits an efficient answer.

Comment: I suggest you add a clear and succinct description of the object you're trying to enumerate to the body of the question.

Comment: This sounds like a question for [scicomp.se].

Comment: @DavidRicherby Disagree. This is combinatorial enumeration.

Comment: @Daniel I still cannot quite understand what a hierarchical partition is. Can you give a definition?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus A "hierarchical" partition or total partition as per Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol 2, pg 13, is the number of ways n objects can be parenthesized. It is a recursive application of set partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unordered hierarchical partition of $n \geq 2$ is composed out of two ingredients:

1. A non-trivial partition $n_1,\ldots,n_k \vdash n$, where $n_1 \leq \cdots \leq n_k$ and $k > 1$.
2. For each $n_i$, an unordered hierarchical partition of $n_i$. Furthermore, if $n_i = n_{i+1}$ then in some fixed order of hierarchical partitions of $n_i$, the one chosen for $n_i$ must precede or equal the one chosen for $n_{i+1}$.

In the base case $n = 1$ there is a single unordered hierarchical partition.

This gives the following algorithm for generating all unordered hierarchical partitions. We generate a list $P^{(n)}_1,\ldots,P^{(n)}_{q(i)}$ of all $q(n)$ unordered hierarchical partitions of $n$. For $n = 1$, the list consists of the single trivial partition. In order to generate the list for $n$:

1. Go over all non-trivial partitions $n_1,\ldots,n_k \vdash n$. We can write this partition more succinctly as $1^{m_1},\ldots,(n-1)^{m_{n-1}}$, where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of $i$.
2. For each $i \in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, make a list of all non-decreasing sequences of length $m_i$ consisting of numbers in $\{1,\ldots,q(i)\}$; there are $\binom{q(i)+m_i-1}{q(i)}$ of these.
3. Each choice of one sequence for each $i$ from the corresponding list corresponds to one unordered hierarchical partition of $n$.

Comment: This is great, I have walked through it several times and see no problems. I'm going to attempt to implement this in Mathematica to verify that this works as intended.

Comment: The reference to a hierarchical partition of $n_i$ in the first point 2. should be an unordered hierarchical partition, shouldn't it? Unordered hierarchical partitions are enumerated by decomposing them into smaller unordered hierarchical partitions. Correct?

Comment: While I requested an efficient method of computing the derivatives of iterated functions, I also indicated that an effective algorithm for enumerating unordered hierarchical partitions, OEIS A000669, would be considered a solution.

Comment: Could you expand upon step 2. of your algorithm? Is there a name for tuples whose indices are only in lexicographically sorted order? I want to avoid having to enumerate all tuple indices and then discard the indices not in sorted order.

Comment: This is "selection with replacement". Perhaps the easiest way to approach this is via the standard bijection showing that the number of ways to choose $k$ out of $n$ with replacement is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$. See the Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition.

Comment: Another approach would be to run a recursive procedure that accepts a "minimum" (originally 1), a "total" ($n$) and a "number" (originally $k$). If you pick $x$, you update the "minimum" to $x$, and in any case you decrease "number" by 1.

Answer (score 0):

@YuvalFilmus has provided an algorithm that I believe answers the question of how to enumerate the ordered hierarchical partitions in terms of unordered hierarchical partitions. Ideally this would be a comment to his answer, but it is too lengthy. I am trying to write Yuval's algorithm in Mathematica as a precursor to coding an efficient way to compute the derivatives of iterated functions.
The following Mathematica code comes close to correctly enumerating the unordered hierarchical partitions.

```
<< Combinatorica`
o[1] = {1};
o[n_ /; n > 1] :=
 Apply[Sequence,
  Map[Tuples, Rest[Partitions[n]] /. m_Integer -> o[m]], 1];
Table[Length[o[i]], {i, 6}]
> {1, 1, 2, 5, 12, 34}
```

The value o[6] should be 33, not 34. This is because the `Tuple` command is used and produces both {{{1,1},1},{1,1,1}} and {{1,1,1},{{1,1},1}} which are the same when unordered.

```
o[3]={{1, 1, 1}, {{1, 1}, 1}}
```

This is where step 2. of Yuval's algorithm comes into play. The following are legitimate values for non-decreasing sequences

```
{o[3][[1]],o[3][[1]]}
> {{{1,1},1},{{1,1},1}}
{o[3][[1]],o[3][[2]]}
> {{{1,1},1},{1,1,1}}
{o[3][[2]],o[3][[2]]}
> {{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}
```

while the following with indices 2, 1 is an invalid decreasing sequence

```
{o[3][[2]],o[3][[1]]}
> {{1,1,1},{{1,1},1}}
```

The `Tuple` command therefore needs to be replaced with a version where no tuple is in non-descending order.